# Migrate from context to Redux

Tags: javascript

I want to migrate a big application from React Context API to Redux. The thing is, since is such a big task, I want to do it slowly and meanwhile be able to work on other things of the app (without adding things to the context).

Is it a good idea to migrate piece by piece and have both Redux and Context in the same app until I migrated everything? Or is it best to freeze the code and migrate it separately, and then work on new things?

I know it might depend on more variables but I want to get a general idea...

Comment: Interested in how you did this, about to do the same

Answer (score 0):

Only you would know the specifics of your app, but in general I don't think there's an issue with doing it piece by piece as you describe (migrating only some slices of state to redux to begin with.) You may find it turns out to be less of a headache to just do it all in one go though, but technically there's no reason you couldn't do this.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously depends on how well you code base is currently structured.
We are about to do the same - i think our approach will be to add more tests to the context side, add redux concurrently with as flat state as possible then do one big move, the addition of redux with context could cause race conditions and other unknowns. Really big and scary change when the day comes to make the change, but hoping that we will have enough tests in place to manage. Wish we started with redux in the first place.